# Join all columns in a while loop

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this loop:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE time INT DEFAULT 1479154801;

  WHILE time <= 1481756399 DO
   SELECT time;
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM phpbb_posts WHERE post_time BETWEEN time AND (time+86400);
    SET time = time + 86400;
  END WHILE;
END
```

Which work as I want it to, but results are not grouped and they look like this:

```
+------------+
| time       |
+------------+
| 1479154801 |
+------------+

+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|      746 |
+----------+

+------------+
| time       |
+------------+
| 1479241201 |
+------------+

+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|      652 |
+----------+

...
```

When I want it to look like this:

```
+------------+----------+
| time       | COUNT(*) |
+------------+----------+
| 1479154801 |      746 |
| 1479241201 |      652 |
...
```

How can I do it? I'm a total newbie when it comes to SQL, so thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want information by day.  Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT date(from_unixtime(post_time)), COUNT(*)
FROM phpbb_posts
GROUP BY date(from_unixtime(post_time));
```

I find dates much more intuitive than Unix timestamps.  If you disagree you can convert the value back using `unix_timestamp()`.

If you prefer the dates, you can just subtract an hour as:

```
SELECT date(date_sub(from_unixtime(post_time), interval 1 hour)) as dte, COUNT(*)
FROM phpbb_posts
GROUP BY date(date_sub(from_unixtime(post_time), interval 1 hour));
```

Or, as the comment suggests, subtract/add 3600 from `post_time`.

Comment: Work exactly as i wanted it to, but how can I adjust it by +1 hour, to match my local time?

Comment: @M.Mar Add or subtract `3600` from `post_time`.